# need to plot two types of data with different color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data like:

```py
x = [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,.....]
w = [5,3,3.4,5,3,5,.....]
y = [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,.....]
```

I need to plot `(x,w)` and the color of this point should be determined by `y` like if I have `x = 1`, `y = 1` and `w = 3`, then this point should be `color1`. And if I have `x = 1`, `y = 0`, then it should be `color2` and `color3` for `x = 0`, `y = 1`, `color4` for `x = 0`, `y = 0`.

I have tried some if else statement but haven't been able to make it work.

my code is:

```py
def plot(x,y,w):
    for (a,b) in zip(x,y):
        if (a,b)==(0,0):
            plt.plot(x,w,'ro')
```

I want to get a different color point for different value of `(x,y)`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use scatter plots  :

```py
import numpy as np
colors = 2 * np.array(x) + np.array(y)
plt.scatter(x,w, c = colors)
```

This chooses the color automatically for you, if you want to use custom colors you could do :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = 2 * np.array(x) + np.array(y)
plt.scatter(x,w, c = colors)
```

If you want to connect the points, you could just do :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colorNames = np.array(['red', 'blue', ...])
colors = 2 * np.array(x) + np.array(y)
plt.scatter(x,w, c = colorNames[colors])
plt.plot(x,w)
```

I consider here that a sequence of 0 and 1 of x and y is a coding of the color in 2 bits

Comment: this will give color only based on y and result in two colors if the value of y is either 0 or 1 but what I need is I have x,y, the value of both x and y is either 0 or 1. depending on this I need 4 different colors for (x=0,y=0,color1) ,(1,1,color2), (1,0,color3) ,(0,1,color4)

Comment: oh ok I guess I misunderstood, T edisted my post, I wish that helps